# AWS Appsync schema query resolver response mapping

Tags: graphql, amazon-rds, aws-appsync

After performing a create mutation, i expect to get the entire response object as shown in
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html

But all i manage to get is the auto generated id (part of the schema) which is of uuid type.

Below is my schema and response mapping :-

**Schema**:-

```
type Apple{
    id: ID!
    type: String
    price: Float
}
```

**Mutation used** :-

```
mutation MyMutation {
  
  updateApple(input: {id: "0a9aa23f-3017-4b67-8dcd-354ef8f609d8", type: "green", price: 10.5}) {
    id
  }
}
======================================================================
type Mutation {
    updateApple(input: UpdateAppleInput!): Apple
}
======================================================================
input UpdateAppleInput {
    id: ID!
    type: String
    price: Float!
}
======================================================================
```

**Response mapping template which returns only id**

```
## Raise a GraphQL field error in case of a datasource invocation error
#if($ctx.error)
    $utils.error($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type)
#end

$utils.toJson($utils.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)[1][0])
```

**Sample response below** (I am expecting the updated "Apple" object):-

```
{
  "data": {
    "updateApple": {
      "id": "0b8bb23f-5613-4b67-8dcd-354ef8f617r5"
    }
  }
}
```

I am referring the example given in :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-rds-resolvers.html#run-queries
And i specifically need the entire Apple object as response when i perform create or update mutations..

EDIT 1: Below response template works fine with a query. Why is it not working with a mutation? :

```
$utils.toJson($utils.rds.toJsonObject($ctx.result)
```

Comment: what query/mutation used? mutation definition?

Comment: Hi @xadm.. i've added the mutation definition